How to get error bars in ggplot2 when the SD is greater than the mean?
I have salinity data where for one month, the standard deviation is greater than the mean. The system is an estuary, and there was a lot of freshwater input that month, so the salinity values in the upper part of the bay are very low (~0.2), while in the upper bay they were still around (~18). I have five sampling sites, and my plot is a monthly average of the values found at all sites. I plotted this as a bar graph with error bars that use the standard deviation values. This is fine, except for the month where SD > mean.

I was wondering if there was a way to make the bar appear with a lower limit just at 0 or something. I want it to look like all of the other bars.
This is the code that I have.
sal <- ggplot(baywide, aes(x = factor(Month, levels = c("SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER","NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER", "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL","may", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST")), y = Salinity))+
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "cornflowerblue", fill = "cornflowerblue", position = position_dodge())+
  theme_classic()+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("Salinity (PSU)")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = 0), limits = c(0, 35), breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Salinity-Salinity_sd, ymax=Salinity+Salinity_sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))+
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("SEP" = "SEP22", "OCT" = "OCT22", "NOV" = "NOV22", "DEC" = "DEC22", "JAN" = "JAN23","FEB" = "FEB23", "MAR" = "MAR23", "APR" = "APR23", "MAY" = "MAY23", "JUN" = "JUN23","JUL" = "JUL23", "AUG" = "AUG23", "SEPTEMBER" = "SEP23", "OCTOBER" = "OCT23", "NOVEMBER" = "NOV23", "DECEMBER" = "DEC23", "JANUARY" = "JAN24", "FEBRUARY" = "FEB24", "MARCH" = "MAR24", "APRIL" = "APR24", "may" = "MAY24", "JUNE" = "JUN24", "JULY" = "JUL24", "AUGUST" = "AUG24"))

print(sal)


See https://r4ds.had.co.nz/graphics-for-communication.html#zooming. scale_y_continuous(limits = ....) will filter out data outside the plotted range. coord_cartesian(ylim = ....) will crop the plot to the requested range, without removing data.

A barplot is just a bad choice for this data ...

@Roland, do you have any alternate suggestions?

Well, a scatter plot or even a line plot could work. Maybe a boxplot or a violin plot, if the uncertainty information is to be the focus of the plot. There are many alternatives. The actual uncertainty is probably assymetric (since salinity can't be negative), so you should probably not use +- SD for the error bars (e.g., you could bootstrap the means or assume some distribution other than the normal distribution to derive and depict confidence intervals).

The challenge you're running into relates to the limits in your scale_y_continuous. Try removing the limits and adding coord_cartesian. I believe that will get you what you're after, if I understand correctly.
testDf <- data.frame(month = factor(c('SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV'), levels = c('SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV')),
                     salinity = c(10, 15, 12),
                     sd = c(14, 8, 3)) 

ggplot(testDf, aes(x = month, y = salinity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = salinity - sd, ymax = salinity + sd)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 25))


